# Conectar um lineEdit a um método de uma classe

Tags: mysql, python

estou tendo uma problema que dá a seguinte mensagem

> TypeError: consultaCodigo() missing 1 required positional argument:
> 'self'

Eu tenho um projeto que até o momento funciona bem em paradigma estruturado, mas estou tentando reescrever o código em POO.

Tenho o seguinte arquivo py " conexao" com o seguinte código:

```
import mysql.connector


# Classe responsável pela conexão ao banco de dados

class Conexao():
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.conectar = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", database="db_farmacia", password="")
        except mysql.connector.Error as e:
            print(e)
        return self.conectar

    def ConsultarTabela(self, consulta):
        try:
            self.cursor = self.conexao_db()
            lista = self.cursor.execute("SELECT nome_produto, preço FROM tb_produtos WHERE codigo=?;", [consulta])
            return lista.fetchall()

        except mysql.connector.Error as e:
            print(e)
        return self.conectar
```

E o seguinte arquivo py com o seguinte código:

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from conexao import Conexao

#Função que insere código

# OBS: inserir_codigo = é um linedEdit


class frenteCaixa:

    def consultaCodigo(self):

        codigo = pdv.inserir_codigo.text()
        pdv.inserir_codigo.setText("")
        consultados = Conexao()
        busca = consultados.ConsultarTabela(codigo)
        print(busca)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
pdv = uic.loadUi("interface_2.ui")
tela_total = uic.loadUi("interface_total.ui")
dial_forma_pgto = uic.loadUi("dialogo_forma_pgto.ui")

pdv.inserir_codigo.returnPressed.connect(frenteCaixa.consultaCodigo) # Utiliza o enter para enviar o código sem necessidade do pushButtom
pdv.showFullScreen()
pdv.show()
app.exec()
```

O meu erro está no código : `pdv.inserir_codigo.returnPressed.connect(frenteCaixa.consultaCodigo)`. No código estruturado está : `pdv.inserir_codigo.returnPressed.connect(funcao_1)` e funciona perfeitamente. No que eu estaria errando?

Answer (score 0):

como sua classe esta com  o atributo self ela precisa ser instanciada antes de usar
você pode instanciar e chamar o metodo consultaCodigo() ou transformar o seu metodo em um class method

```py
# 1 solução
pdv.inserir_codigo.returnPressed.connect(frenteCaixa().consultaCodigo)

# 2 solução
@classmethod
def consultaCodigo(cls):
     #seu codigo

pdv.inserir_codigo.returnPressed.connect(frenteCaixa.consultaCodigo)
```

Comment: Olá JooJ, obrigado pela resposta e pela ajuda, a solução 1 não faz mais travar, mas não consigo enviar também, ao pressionar enter no lineEdit, ele deveria enviar o código, isso não está funcionando. 

Consegui funcionamento na solução 2, mas sem importar o módulo conexão, incluí a consulta no banco de dados e fetchall no código mesmo e com o class method funcionou! 

Muito obrigado, depois preciso refazer com calma o módulo "Conexao".

Comment: Em todo caso seu comentário já ensinou muito sobre POO!